# SSMS: Extract a single row as an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am debugging a weird bug in our system that happens *sometimes* but quite rarely. I have a hard time reproducing it so I want to take a single existing faulty row in the database, save it in some way, and test something, and then insert that row back into the table.

I am thinking that there would be a way to select the row as an insert statement to easily add it back again.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.8.1

Comment: By *"Select the row as an insert statement to easily add it back again."* Do you mean the `SELECT...INTO...FROM` or `INSERT...SELECT...FROM...` Syntax?

Comment: Why don't you make a copy of table and use it later to bring back the original data?

Comment: @Larnu I mean that there would be a way in SSMS to get the data in the row as SQL statement string like `INSERT INTO [table] (all_rows)  VALUES (all_data_for_the_respective_columns)`

Comment: @akshay Because I only want to work with a single row a time. And remove and add that back multiple times

Comment: Why `VALUES`? Why not `INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT * FROM OriginalTable WHERE RowID = {Offending ID};`?

Comment: @Larnu I don't want to move data from one table to another. I want to save a row and later add that row back again into the same table

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't move data. There is, in fact, no "move" functionality in SQL Server. To "move" something you would have to perform an `INSERT` the put the data in the new table, and then use `DELETE` on the old one. If you are only performing an `INSERT` you are only copying, not moving.

Comment: @Larnu fine, copy then, you nitpicker you :)

Comment: So, if you don;t want to copy or move the data, where are you expecting it to go? You can't make a row disappear and reappear unless you put that data elsewhere first, or `ROLLBACK` the transaction (and that works because technically the deleted data is in the transaction log).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you "edit top 100" you can select a whole row, copy it, and paste it back as a new row. The trick is to click to the left of the row as you would in Excel to select the entire row.

You would either have to not have the primary key in the list of columns or turn on IDENTITY INSERT. whichever is easiest for your situation.